# 2 textbox with same event reset global variable?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I got 2 text boxes and a label. Both text boxes have the same event handler which is generic for any text box. The problem is that when I try to add both values from text boxes to the global variable, I am only displayed the value from the latest modified text box?

Both text boxes have `AutoPostBack="True"`

What am I doing wrong here?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int total;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;

        total += int.Parse(tb.Text);

        Label1.Text = total.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code I only see you accessing ONE textbox, where is the other one? Can you also show me your ASPX? You are probably better off using JQuerey and update a Hidden textbox? I dont think SENDER can hold "two" objects, it will most likely hold the object that was last changed... If you go that route you will probably use WebMethods to trigger server-side action.. I can help you with that.

Comment: This event I meant to be generic for any text box I might use... This is my simple example, but I must have like 30 of them and all are different categories. So I do this this way? (TextBox)sender is a bad idea?

Comment: I think its a bad idea, go with JQuerey and WebMethods, if you need help let me know

Comment: I think managing 30+ of them server-side might actually be slow? If all you are doing is calculating a total then do it using JavaScript, and then invoke a WebMethod when you want to do a server-side action with that total variable...

Comment: Search for "ASP.Net - how to store value between postbacks" you should find your answer in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both textboxes have `AutoPostBack="True"`, `textbox_TextChanged` handler executed on separate postbacks and since total field doesn't persisted in either ViewState or Session, it have 0 initial value on each `textbox_TextChanged` method ran. You need to explicitely calculate total value from two textboxes like this:

```
protected void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var total = int.Parse(textBox1.Text) + int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

    Label1.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

Of course, better use TryParse method and check Text property for null and empty string values.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I want to add a value of last changed value to the total value. This way I don't have to fill out all the text fields.

Comment: Let's assume that user will change text of first textbox twice: first time print 10 and after that 20. Should total must be 30?

Comment: Yes, true. I would rather not hard code anything... But I guess I'll just split ID on chars and so on... I think that solves my problem LOL.

Answer (score 1):

The variable 'total' is reset for every postback. You can use event 'TextChanged' for the addition of two text boxes. So try this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int total;        

        total = int.Parse(this.TextBox1.Text) + int.Parse(this.TextBox2.Text);

        Label1.Text = total.ToString();
    }
}
```

We should also put in try/catch block....

Comment: +1 for pointing out that each time the handles is used, the variable will reset.